# toFixed rounds at 6 why not 5?

Tags: javascript

I expected `50.65.toFixed(1)` will returns `"50.7"` because it rounds at 0.05, but got `"50.6"`

I tested the other case: `50.66.toFixed(1)` it returns `'50.7'`.

Why is it not rounds at 5? Any ideas?

I've read [TC39](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-number.prototype.tofixed), but failed to understand.

```
console.log(100.15.toFixed(1)) // 100.2 (OK)
console.log(123.45.toFixed(1)) // 123.5 (OK)
console.log(50.65.toFixed(1)) // 50.6 (what??)
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What did you expect those lines of code to return?

Comment: I just edited the question. But it's yet to be approved by the community. The actual question is, why parseFloat() rounds numbers with 5/100th to the floor, and Math.round() rounds it to the ceiling?

Comment: `toFixed(1)` rounds the number to 1 decimal place, `toFixed(0)` is what you're looking for.

Comment: This behavior comes from the imprecision of floating point numbers. Math.abs(50.65 - 50.6) == 0.04999... and Math.abs(50.65 - 50.7) == 0.0500...
So the closest round is down to 50.6

Comment: This behaviour is noted on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rounding method for `toFixed` is described in https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-number.prototype.tofixed as *"Let n be an integer for which n / 10^f - x is as close to zero as possible. If there are two such n, pick the larger n."*

and `506 / 10 - 50.65` is nearer to zero than `507 / 10 - 50.65`

You can test it with:

```js
if (Math.abs(506 / 10 - 50.65) < Math.abs(507 / 10 - 50.65)) {
    console.log(1);
} else {
    console.log(2);
}
```

but `1001 / 10 - 100.15` isn't nearer than `1002 / 10 - 100.15`

```js
if (Math.abs(1001 / 10 - 101.15) < Math.abs(1002 / 10 - 101.15)) {
    console.log(1);
} else {
    console.log(2);
}
```

therefore it's round up.

Comment: So `60.15.toFixed(1)` = 60.1, `70.15.toFixed(1)` = 70.2 that's .... ummm a bit rubbish.

Comment: @BenStephens But obviously that's the most exact. It reduces the rounding error. If you want to avoid surprises you can round before :-)

Comment: I'm sure you're right for whatever use case the specification had in mind, but I can't think of any actual scenario I've encountered where I'd want this behaviour.

Comment: In Javascript all is possible. Welcome to the Javascript Magic Show, where `0.5 + 0.1 == 0.6` is **true**, but `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` is **false**.

Comment: If `50.65.toFixed(1)` then `Math.abs(506/10-50.65) = 0.04...`, `Math.abs(505/10-50.65) = 0.14...` so pick `506` as `n` and `a = 50`, `b = 6` so it returns `50.6`

Comment: @JillAndMe You have to check the nearsest possiblities 50.6 and 50.7. Obviously 50.5 is not an option. `Math.abs(506/10-50.65) = 0.04...` and `Math.abs(507/10-50.65) = 0.04...`